# backbone view events are not working in Android Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, backbone.js, marionette

This Is first time,I am working on mobile based Application.We finished an Application,it supports both `desktop and tablet`.If you open same Application in `Mobile`,it's not appearing properly.So we decided to change way of show the Application in mobile compare with desktop and tablet.As per specs my `HTML` guy made mobile pages.

In backbone side,I don't need to change `model` events.I am facing a problem in view events especially `keyboard` events.What I written same code working fine in `desktop and tablet` but it's not working in `mobile`.

Code:

events:{"keypress input[type=text]":"typeOfField"},

```
typeOfField:function(){
   //finding Ascii value of the press key
   var keyAsciiValue=event.keyCode||event.which;
   //declaring dummy variable for passing result
   var result=false;
   if ((keyAsciiValue>=48&&keyAsciiValue<=57)||(keyAsciiValue===46)||(keyAsciiValue===45)){
        //text-field allows any numbers like 23.8,30...
        result=true;
    }else{
        result=false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

code description:

If user press on any key,fetching corresponding `ASCII`value and checking whether the key is character or number.If it is number then only returning `true` otherwise returning `false`.Finally in my application `textFields` allows only `numbers`.

What I am facing problems:

1. `textField` allowing all the values(like characters,numbers ...)
2. I can't able to delete the last character.

If `mobile` events are different compare with `desktop,tablet` events,can you suggest any tutorials for my reference.

I googled but I didn't find any tutorials.

For your testing,I made [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33Snz/).If you open this link in `desktop or tablet` it's working fine as per specs.But it's not working in `mobile`.It's allowing `characters` also in `mobile`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that keypress event is not fired in Android before you confirm your input. You may use keyup event for your task.

For the second problem, it should be just because the events are not fired correctly as expected.

Comment: As per `javascript` documentation,`keyPress` event fire while keyPress time,`keyUp` event fire after releasing the key.So I think `keyUp` not useful.anyhow I will check it once.

Comment: I tested and the keyup event is fired correctly. However if you insist on using keypress event which should be fired before updating the field. You may want to take a look on this document, the beforeinput and input events.
[http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a problem,but it won't work in `opera`.Instead of writing the code for numeric fields.I just added an attribute `type='number'` to input field in html file.Now only `numeric` keypad is coming.So it satisfies my requirements.